# how to decide spark yarn config properties

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

We are using Apache spark open source cluster and I have a below config.

```
Total 6 nodes.
32GB per node
16 PUS per node
```

Can someone help me in finding the right values for below properties.

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb

yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb

yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores
```

Is above properties impact job timings?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb,yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb specifies maximum memory that can be allocated to a container and yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores specifies maximum number of cores that can be allocated to a container.

By default yarn will allocate one cpu core and 1GB memory for a container(executor in spark) and also by default yarn will create 2 containers(2 executors) for a spark application.

We can override the number of cores and amount of memory for an executor by using below properties
--conf spark.executor.memory=4g , --conf spark.executor.cores=2

Also we can override number of executors for a spark application by using below property
--conf spark.executor.instances=3